# TAction.ShortCut not working in dynamically created TAction

Tags: delphi, ribbon, shortcut, delphi-xe5

In Delphi XE5: I have a TActionManager (called ActionManager) and a TRibbon (called Ribbon) on my form. I am adding a custom action like this:

```
ActionBar := ActionManager.ActionBars.Add;
newAction := TAction.Create(MainForm.ActionManager);
newAction.Name := 'Topics';
newAction.Caption := 'Topics';
newAction.OnExecute := MainForm.HelpTopicsItemClick;
newMenu := ActionBar.Items.Add;
newMenu.Action := newAction;
newAction.ShortCut := TextToShortCut('F1');
```

After this I place them on a ribbon in a page/tab and in a group:

```
rp := TRibbonPage.Create(ActionManager);
rp.Parent := Ribbon;
Ribbon.AddTab(rp).Caption := 'Help';
rg := TRibbonGroup.Create(ActionManager);
rg.Parent := rp;
rg.ActionManager := ActionManager;
rg.Caption := 'Help';
rg.ActionClient := ActionBar;
```

The action works fine when I click it, However when I press 'F1' nothing happens. When I add the action manually using the Delphi editors the shortcuts work fine.

I already tried: newMenu.ShortCut := newAction.ShortCut

This doesn't help. What am I missing?

Comment: F1 is reserved for help, I guess. Try with a different shortcut.

Comment: Is also doesn't not work for other shortcuts like TextToShortCut('CTRL+H')

Comment: Is `ActionManager` and `MainForm.ActionManager` the same?

Comment: Yes they are. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a new action its ActionList property is not automatically set to the Owner you provide with Create. You have to set ActionList explicitely to make it work.

```
newAction := TAction.Create(MainForm.ActionManager);
newAction.ActionList := MainForm.ActionManager;
newAction.Name := 'Topics';
```

Comment: This worked! However the shortcut still isn't showing in the caption of the ActionClient. Any ideas? Or is this how the Ribbon was intended?